# Fast indexed dot-product for numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython, blas

I'm using numpy to do linear algebra. I want to do **fast subset-indexed** `dot` and other linear operations.

When dealing with big matrices, slicing solution like `A[:,subset].dot(x[subset])` may be longer than doing the multiplication on the full matrix.

```
A = np.random.randn(1000,10000)
x = np.random.randn(10000,1)
subset = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,10000,500))
```

Timings show that sub-indexing can be faster when columns are in one block.

```
%timeit A.dot(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.19 ms per loop

%timeit A[:,subset].dot(x[subset])
100 loops, best of 3: 7.36 ms per loop

%timeit A[:,:500].dot(x[:500])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.75 ms per loop
```

Still the acceleration is not what I would expect (20x faster!).

Does anyone know an idea of a library/module that allow these kind of fast operation through numpy or scipy?

For now on I'm using cython to code a fast column-indexed dot product through the cblas library. But for more complex operation (pseudo-inverse, or subindexed least square solving) I'm not shure to reach good acceleration.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you expect 20x speedup?

Comment: Naively, computing the result for 10000 columns should be 20x faster than computing 500.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is faster.

```
%timeit A.dot(x)
#4.67 ms

%%timeit
y = numpy.zeros_like(x)
y[subset]=x[subset]
d = A.dot(y)
#4.77ms

%timeit c = A[:,subset].dot(x[subset])
#7.21ms
```

And you have `all(d-ravel(c)==0) == True`.

Notice that how fast this is depends on the input. With `subset = array([1,2,3])` you have that the time of my solution is pretty much the same, while the timing of the last solution is `46micro seconds`.

Basically this will be faster if the size of`subset` is not much smaller than  the size of `x`

Comment: Yes, but I'm still far from the 20x speed-up I expect.

Comment: You can't expect a 20x speed-up, because you are processing data that is non-contiguous, and this likely leads to a slower computation

Comment: Yes, you're right, but when processing 'F' contiguous array, you can reach good speed-up, using for example cython interface for cblas library. I was actually wandering if there was module that can allow similar or better speed up in a easy to use way, and for more complex operation.

Comment: With a random index it doesn't much matter whether the order is F or C.  Look at the timing of `A[:,subset]`.  This is far larger than doing `dot` on 500 columns.

Comment: @TonioBonnef To add to hpaulj's comment, [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) (e.g. with an array of integer indices) always returns a copy of the data rather than a view, so you need to take into account the additional cost of allocating a new array when you do  `A[:, subset]`, as well as the fact that you are indexing non-contiguous blocks of `A`.

Comment: Yes and this is actually my problem. So is there a way to make such computation without slicing/indexing, to avoid the additional cost of the allocation of the new array? Or how to work directly on the data contained in A?